# Cannot find GRUB configuration file

Tags: configuration, grub2

I have been looking for the GRUB configuration file, and I haven't had much luck. According to the sites I found, it should be at '/boot/grub/menu.lst'. But, I went to that file path, and could not find menu.lst. Can anyone tell me why it isn't there, and where I might locate it? I would like to change the default system to boot, but I cannot find any related files to help me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Recent releases of Ubuntu have migrated to GRUB2.
From the [wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Configuring%20GRUB%202):

> Configuring GRUB 2
>
> Important note: Configuration changes
>   are normally made to /etc/default/grub
>   and to the custom files located in
>   /etc/grub.d. The /boot/grub/grub.cfg
>   file should not be edited by the user;
>   changes to this file are made by
>   configuration scripts. After editing
>   /etc/default/grub, you need to run
>   sudo update-grub for your changes to
>   take effect on the next boot.

Comment: I tried editing the file in etc/default, but it is read-only. Then, when I tried changing it, it told me I did not have permissions to do so. Is there something else I need to change?

Comment: @B3tturTh3nU: You need to edit the file with root privileges. Use `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub` or `sudoedit /etc/default/grub` or `sudo nano /etc/default/grub`. Careful with the editing! :)